# Scrolling text in UItextfield when cursor is at the corner of uitextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture

I am trying to move cursor of UITextfield on pan gesture . But I am facing some problems .

I have a UITextfield and UIView (same size of UITextfield).

I have added pan gesture on UIView as I want to move cursor position of UITextfield by dragging finger on UIView

but when I am moving cursor position and cursor comes at the corner of UITextfield , text scrolling does not take place.

can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

**Code :**

```
-(void)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{

CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:btnMove];
CGPoint vel = [pan velocityInView:btnMove];

UITextRange *range = txtSearch.selectedTextRange;
NSInteger endOffset = [txtSearch offsetFromPosition:txtSearch.beginningOfDocument toPosition:range.end];

if (vel.x > 0)
{

    endOffset = endOffset + 1;

    NSLog(@"right - %ld",(long)endOffset);

}
else{

    endOffset = endOffset - 1;

    NSLog(@"left - %ld",(long)endOffset);

}

UITextPosition *from = [txtSearch positionFromPosition:[txtSearch beginningOfDocument] offset:endOffset];
UITextPosition *to = [txtSearch positionFromPosition:[txtSearch beginningOfDocument] offset:endOffset];

txtSearch.selectedTextRange = [txtSearch textRangeFromPosition:from toPosition:to];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is for iOS 6? I haven't had any problems with 7, but 6 has been a bear. This worked for me, but I have no idea why. After setting your selected text range, try adding this line:

```
[txtSearch setBaseWritingDirection:UITextWritingDirectionNatural forRange:txtSearch.selectedTextRange];
```